opentelemetry in nestjs with winston set no tractId nor spanId
trying to set opentelemetry running to send my application logs with other tracing information.
Instrumentation for nestjs, http, express and pg are OK, but I could not make winston instrumentation running well.
I tried the the official example in the winston instrumentation repo, but I have no spanId nor traceId as shown below.

I tried also using the SDK instead of API but still no luck. Anyone has make it work ?
my API code
import { NodeTracerProvider } from '@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-node';

import { logs } from '@opentelemetry/api-logs';
import {
  ConsoleLogRecordExporter,
  LoggerProvider,
  SimpleLogRecordProcessor,
} from '@opentelemetry/sdk-logs';

import { registerInstrumentations } from '@opentelemetry/instrumentation';
import { NestInstrumentation } from '@opentelemetry/instrumentation-nestjs-core';
import { PgInstrumentation } from '@opentelemetry/instrumentation-pg';
import { WinstonInstrumentation } from '@opentelemetry/instrumentation-winston';
const tracerProvider = new NodeTracerProvider();
tracerProvider.register();

const loggerProvider = new LoggerProvider();
// Add a processor to export log record
loggerProvider.addLogRecordProcessor(
  new SimpleLogRecordProcessor(new ConsoleLogRecordExporter()),
);
logs.setGlobalLoggerProvider(loggerProvider);

registerInstrumentations({
  instrumentations: [
    new WinstonInstrumentation({
      enabled: true,
    }),
    new NestInstrumentation(),
    new PgInstrumentation(),
  ],
});

